# inserting varchar2 field with python

Tags: python, database, varchar2

I have varchar2 fields in  my databases (Oracle and Impala) and I want to insert string fields into this fields. I could not insert the values as string as normally. I got following error

> AnalysisException: Possible loss of precision for target table
>   'test01.testdcr'. Expression ''data1 data2 data3 data4 '' (type:
>   STRING) would need to be cast to VARCHAR(128) for column
>   'testVarchar2Field'

How can I convert string variable to varchar2 while inserting into table ?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentations](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-0-x/topics/impala_conversion_functions.html), there is a cast function that works like:

```
select concat('Here are the first ',10,' results.'); -- Fails
select concat('Here are the first ',cast(10 as string),' results.'); -- Succeeds
```

They also state [somewhere else](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/cdh/5-0-x/Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_insert.html) this other example:

> When you insert the results of an expression, particularly of a
>   built-in function call, into a small numeric column such as INT,
>   SMALLINT, TINYINT, or FLOAT, you might need to use a CAST() expression
>   to coerce values into the appropriate type. Impala does not
>   automatically convert from a larger type to a smaller one. For
>   example, to insert cosine values into a FLOAT column, write
>   CAST(COS(angle) AS FLOAT) in the INSERT statement to make the
>   conversion explicit.

Doesn't it solve your problem?